# OR function for beautifulsoup's find_all?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to scrape a website for data, and the actual text is held in cells of alternating colors.
they alternate between "#ECEBE1" and "White", so i want to search for  with both of those. the command im thinking of would look something like
`table=soup.find_all(tr, bgcolor="#ECEBE1" OR bgcolor="White",)`
but im not sure if that function exists or how i would do something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) soup can match against a `list`, so you can just use:

```
table=soup.find_all(tr, bgcolor=["#ECEBE1", "White"])
```

Comment: oooh sick thanks. i tried looking through the beautifulsoup documentation myself but didn't notice that.